# How can I fix my python installation?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, installation, uninstallation

For some work I'm doing at my office I needed to downgrade my python version from 2.7.9 (OS X default installation) to 2.7.6. It seemed the easiest way to do this would be to uninstall python and then reinstall the older version. After following the [instructions here](http://technomess.blogspot.com/2011/04/python-27-mac-os-x-uninstall.html) and then running the official Python 2.7.6 installer. I then tried to just run `python` in the terminal to make sure the installation worked and received this error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Running `python --version` gave the same results. `which python` yielded the following directory:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this issue to get the right version of Python running? I'm pretty much out of ideas at this point.

Comment: have to ask, why did you have to go from 2.7.9 to 2.7.6?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham haha kind of expected this one...we use a library that, when connecting to an external server with a self-signed certificate, fails the SSL handshake on 2.7.9 because of a change made in 2.7.7.

Comment: Virtualenv seems like a better idea than mucking about with you system Python.

Comment: Interesting, I had to ask :) what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham /usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python

Comment: ok there is some strange goings on pathwise. Does either `/usr/bin/python`  or `/usr/local/bin/python` start an interpreter?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham both commands start a 2.7.6 interpreter, so I guess technically the installation worked?

Comment: There is still a link between the `/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/python:` and python. You need to be very careful when doing anything with your system python. You can symlink.

Comment: Where did you install python 2.7.6 ? I assume you used brew so that it is in ```/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/bin/python```

Comment: I would just put an alias in ```~/.bashrc``` ... Something like ```alias python2.7.6="path/to/python276"``` Then ```source ~/.bashrc``` and you are good to go, just execute your python script with your new alias. Also, any time you want to extend that python dist, be sure to use the alias and not your system python variable.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the problem is I need to be able to use Python in an IDE, so just a symlink or bash alias won't do it, I need IntelliJ to see it as a standard install of python

Comment: @dermen same response^

Comment: Dont you set the interpreter in your ide?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, would've been nice to have it be a default though. oh well, I guess this'll do. That's what I get for messing with system files I suppose

Comment: @PadraicCunningham want to post your solution as an answer so I can give you some credit?

Comment: I will add a way to restore everything back to normal when i get back on my comp

Answer (score 0):

The symlink in/usr/local/bin/Python is still pointing to the other version. Update it to point to the version currently installed and it should work.

Comment: I need to be able to use Python in an IDE, so just a symlink or bash alias won't do it, I need IntelliJ to see it as a standard install of python